# Flutter Retrofit issue with two different json response in one API

Tags: flutter, retrofit

I have been using Retrofit for API calling. In one of the API sending two different response and trying to get them in `Map<String, dynamic>` But in generated file it is showing error.

[image]

When i take response type as Map<String, String> for one of the response is fine but in other response have different types of keys. Exception is being caught when type is `Map<String, String>` and Json keys has int value.

One response

```
   {
  "count": 1,
  "login_type": "PASSWORD",
  "success": true,
  "type": "object",
  "data": {
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 1200,
    "access_token": "1o+BYL3LWRs+JpHMK3E5",
    "refresh_token": "OAPwbwFORpQ0R6sg",
    "userId": 358
  }
}
```

Other response

> {"count":1,"type":"success","data":{"success":true,"otpEnabled":true,"message":"OTP has been sent to your mobile no 62*****32","timestamp":"","otp":572800}}

Error

> type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: Could you please share the JSON URL or JSON file?

Comment: @DharamBudh response updated

Comment: Do you want to use one generic model or two separate models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI:

```
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: firstAPI,
          child: const Text("Call First"),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: secondAPI,
          child: const Text("Call Second API"),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

First API Call (One response):

```
  Future<void> firstAPI() async {
    const String path = "https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/99ID"; // hosted One res
    final Response<dynamic> res = await Dio().get(path);
    final FirstModel firstModel = FirstModel.fromJson(res.data);
    log("firstAPI(): ${firstModel.toJson()}");
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
```

Second API Call (Other response):

```
  Future<void> secondAPI() async {
    const String path = "https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/49KW"; // hosted Other res
    final Response<dynamic> res = await Dio().get(path);
    final SecondModel secondModel = SecondModel.fromJson(res.data);
    log("secondAPI(): ${secondModel.toJson()}");
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
```

first_model.dart:

```
class FirstModel {
  FirstModel({this.count, this.loginType, this.success, this.type, this.data});

  FirstModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    count = json["count"];
    loginType = json["login_type"];
    success = json["success"];
    type = json["type"];
    data = json["data"] != null ? Data.fromJson(json["data"]) : null;
  }
  int? count;
  String? loginType;
  bool? success;
  String? type;
  Data? data;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data["count"] = count;
    data["login_type"] = loginType;
    data["success"] = success;
    data["type"] = type;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data["data"] = this.data!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  Data({
    this.tokenType,
    this.expiresIn,
    this.accessToken,
    this.refreshToken,
    this.userId,
  });

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    tokenType = json["token_type"];
    expiresIn = json["expires_in"];
    accessToken = json["access_token"];
    refreshToken = json["refresh_token"];
    userId = json["userId"];
  }
  String? tokenType;
  int? expiresIn;
  String? accessToken;
  String? refreshToken;
  int? userId;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data["token_type"] = tokenType;
    data["expires_in"] = expiresIn;
    data["access_token"] = accessToken;
    data["refresh_token"] = refreshToken;
    data["userId"] = userId;
    return data;
  }
}
```

second_model.dart:

```
class SecondModel {
  SecondModel({this.count, this.type, this.data});

  SecondModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    count = json["count"];
    type = json["type"];
    data = json["data"] != null ? Data.fromJson(json["data"]) : null;
  }
  int? count;
  String? type;
  Data? data;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data["count"] = count;
    data["type"] = type;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data["data"] = this.data!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  Data({this.success, this.otpEnabled, this.message, this.timestamp, this.otp});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    success = json["success"];
    otpEnabled = json["otpEnabled"];
    message = json["message"];
    timestamp = json["timestamp"];
    otp = json["otp"];
  }
  bool? success;
  bool? otpEnabled;
  String? message;
  String? timestamp;
  int? otp;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data["success"] = success;
    data["otpEnabled"] = otpEnabled;
    data["message"] = message;
    data["timestamp"] = timestamp;
    data["otp"] = otp;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: @farhana-naaz-ansari, I did this with a separate model approach. If you want a generic model approach, then respond to me.

Comment: There is only one api and we don't know what response will come

Comment: Do you want a generic model approach?

Comment: I made generic model

Comment: Great! Best of luck!